# flutter too many positional arguments

Tags: flutter

I was trying to make both the sideview menu and search bar (textfield) in row but textfield is giving too many positional errors and i tried all possible solutions on stackoverflow and github and still dont get it .

here:

```
{

return Padding(
 padding:  EdgeInsets.all(30),
    child:Row(
TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'Search..',
        prefixIcon: Align(
          widthFactor: 1.0,
          heightFactor: 1.0,
          child: Icon( Icons.search,),),
      ),
           ),/
      
    Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: <Widget>[
      DrawerHeader(
        child: Text(
          'Side menu',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green,
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/cover.jpg'))),
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.input),
        title: Text('Welcome'),
        onTap: () => {},
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.verified_user),
        title: Text('Profile'),
        onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
        title: Text('Settings'),
        onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.border_color),
        title: Text('Feedback'),
        onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
        title: Text('Logout'),
        onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
      ),
    ],
  ),
),



), 
);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you put the `textfield()` and `drawer()` into `Row()` widget incorrectly.

Here is a correct sample:

```
Row(children:[Textfield(),Drawer,],),
```

When adding values for `Row()` and `Column()` you will need to add it into the `children` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
}
return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            const TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Search..',
                prefixIcon: Align(
                  widthFactor: 1.0,
                  heightFactor: 1.0,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Drawer(
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const DrawerHeader(
                    child: Text(
                      'Side menu',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            image: AssetImage('assets/images/cover.jpg'))),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.input),
                    title: const Text('Welcome'),
                    onTap: () => {},
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.verified_user),
                    title: const Text('Profile'),
                    onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                    title: const Text('Settings'),
                    onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.border_color),
                    title: const Text('Feedback'),
                    onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                    title: const Text('Logout'),
                    onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Comment: if someone might need it in future.